# How important is NTFS Allocation Unit Size really, in terms of read/write performance and fragmentation?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

**Specifically on large media drives.** I'm interested in this subject because I just purchased a 8TB external hard drive (WD White Label) that is specifically going to be used to store hi-res images, music, and 1080p/4k video files. I also plan on editing some of these files as needed, so fragmentation is to be expected. My goal is to use an optimal AUS size with a good balance between speed and fragmentation prevention. Images will be the smallest files and will average around 1mb each.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about fragmentation. I will be editing thousands of images on this drive. Does cluster size affect defragmentation speed?

Comment: I decided to use a 1MB cluster size. Biswapriyo's link answered my question.